# RegEx for extracting a value from Open3.popen3 stdout

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-group

How do I get the output of an external command and extract values from it?

I have something like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3("#{path}/foobar", configfile)

if /exit 0/ =~ wait_thr.value.to_s
    runlog.puts("Foobar exited normally.\n")
    puts "Test completed."
    someoutputvalue = stdout.read("TX.*\s+(\d+)\s+")
    puts "Output value: " + someoutputvalue
end
```

I'm not using the right method on stdout since Ruby tells me it can't convert String into Integer.

So for instance, if the output is

```
"TX So and so:     28"
```

I would like to get only "`28`". I validated that the regex above matches what I need to match, I'm only wondering how to store that extracted value in a variable.

What is the right way of doing this? I can't find anywhere in the documentation the methods available for stdout. I'm using `stout.read` from Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: If you don't want to communicate to the process and just read its output, `capture3` would be more appropriate (and more simple).

Comment: What's the argument to read do? I thought the only argument you passed was how far into the stream to go? Maybe it's trying to treat your string argument as the integer number of bytes?

Comment: @JoePym the argument is an XML file used by foobar to run, if that's your question.

Comment: I think that's the problem:  Open3.popen3("grep") do |stin,stdout,stderr| stdout.read("aaaa") end raises the same error. Your argument to read in a stream case is the number of bytes to seek into the stream.

Comment: Is there anyway to apply a regex to the stream and instead of seeking to bytes? I guess that's the core question due to my lack of knowledge on Ruby methods :)

Comment: `capture3` is the simple way of executing something if you don't need to pass anything in via STDIN.

Answer (score 15):

All the information needed is in the [Popen3 documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html), but you have to read it all and look at the examples pretty carefully. You can also glean useful information from the [Process docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html) too.

Maybe this will 'splain it better:

```
require 'open3'

captured_stdout = ''
captured_stderr = ''
exit_status = Open3.popen3(ENV, 'date') {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  pid = wait_thr.pid # pid of the started process.
  stdin.close
  captured_stdout = stdout.read
  captured_stderr = stderr.read
  wait_thr.value # Process::Status object returned.
}

puts "STDOUT: " + captured_stdout
puts "STDERR: " + captured_stderr
puts "EXIT STATUS: " + (exit_status.success? ? 'succeeded' : 'failed')
```

Running that outputs:

```
STDOUT: Wed Jun 12 07:07:12 MST 2013
STDERR:
EXIT STATUS: succeeded
```

Things to note:

- You often have to `close` the `stdin` stream. If the called application expects input on STDIN it will hang until it sees the stream close, then will continue its processing.
- `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` are IO handles, so you have to read the [IO class documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html) to find out what methods are available.
- You have to output to `stdin` using `puts`, `print` or `write`, and `read` or `gets` from `stdout` and `stderr`.
- `exit_status` isn't a string, it's an instance of the Process::Status class. You can mess with trying to parse from its `to_s` version, but don't. Instead use the accessors to see what it returned.
- I passed in the `ENV` hash, so the child program had access to the entire environment the parent saw. It's not necessary to do that; Instead you can create a reduced environment for the child if you don't want it to have access to everything, or you can mess with its view of the environment by changing values.
- The code `stdout.read("TX.*\s+(\d+)\s+")` posted in the question is, um... nonsense. I have no idea where you got that as nothing like that is documented in Ruby's IO class for [IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-read) or [IO.read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read).

It's easier to use `capture3` if you don't need to write to STDIN of the called code:

```
require 'open3'

stdout, stderr, exit_status = Open3.capture3('date')

puts "STDOUT: " + stdout
puts "STDERR: " + stderr
puts "EXIT STATUS: " + (exit_status.success? ? 'succeeded' : 'failed')
```

Which outputs:

```
STDOUT: Wed Jun 12 07:23:23 MST 2013
STDERR:
EXIT STATUS: succeeded
```

---

Extracting a value from a string using a regular expression is trivial, and well covered by the [Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html). Starting from the last code example:

```
stdout[/^\w+ (\w+ \d+) .+ (\d+)$/]
puts "Today is: " + [$1, $2].join(' ')
```

Which outputs:

```
Today is: Jun 12 2013
```

That's using the [`String.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method which is extremely flexible.

An alternate is using "named captures":

```
/^\w+ (?<mon_day>\w+ \d+) .+ (?<year>\d+)$/ =~ stdout
puts "Today is: #{ mon_day } #{ year }"
```

which outputs the same thing. The downside to named captures is they're slower for what I consider a minor bit of convenience.

---

```
"TX So and so: 28"[/\d+$/]
=> "28"
```

Comment: But if I just `puts stdout.read` it prints correctly, why is the use of an intermediate variable necessary (in my case the regex is done in the block so there's no scope issue) ? How would I extract a value using a regex on captured_stdout in your example?

Comment: I stored it in an intermediate variable to show you how to access that from outside the block. If you don't need to do that then don't. And, you'd use a normal regular expression or a substring to extract a value from `captured_stdout`, there's nothing mysterious or magical, it's a string containing whatever the called code returns.

Comment: I have read the documentation closely, my question is more general around Ruby, basically asking how to store a value extracted from a string through a regular expression, which is not covered by the Popen3 documentation.. nor the Regexp documentation as far as I can tell. The example you gave is already working for me, since I have read the documentation.

Comment: Then your question is a red-herring. If you want to know how to use Regular expressions reduce your question to just that. I'll add an example.