# Running an interactive program from Ruby

Tags: ruby, stdout, popen, interactive

I am trying to run gnuplot from ruby (not using an external gem) and parsing its textual output also. I tried `IO.popen`, `PTY.spawn` and `Open3.popen3` but whenever I try to get the output it just "hangs" -I guess waiting for more output to come. I feel like its somehow done using `Thread.new` but I couldn't find the correct way to implement it.

Anyone know how it is done?

Comment: If that's standard output, try getting it via a shell command. Either enclose your command in backticks (`\`command\``) or use `%x(command)`

Comment: I am trying to run an **interactive** program.

Comment: Somehow I missed the heading. Sorry. What exactly have you tried with `Open3`?

Comment: `i, o, e, th = Open3.popen3('gnuplot');
putc o.readchar while !o.eof? `

Comment: See "[Extracting value from stdout of Open3.popen3 through RegEx and store it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067010/extracting-value-from-stdout-of-open3-popen3-through-regex-and-store-it/17067673#17067673)", which is most likely the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn('gnuplot') do |input, output, pid|
  str = input.expect(/gnuplot>/)
  puts str
  output.puts "mlqksdf"

  str = input.expect(/gnuplot>/)
  puts str
  output.puts "exit"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the sub-program is waiting for input that isn't being sent.

Typically, when we call a program that expects input on STDIN, we have to close STDIN, which then signals that program to begin processing. Look through the various [Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) methods and you'll see where `stdin.close` occurs in many examples, but they don't explain why.

Open3 also includes [`capture2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) and [`capture3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture3), which make it nice when trying to deal with a program that wants STDIN and you don't have anything to send to it. In both methods, STDIN is immediately closed, and the method returns the STDOUT, STDERR and exit status of the called program.

---

You need "expect" functionality. Ruby's [Pty](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) class includes an [`expect`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/pty/rdoc/IO.html) method.

> Creates and managed pseudo terminals (PTYs). See also en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal

It's not very well documented though, and doesn't offer a lot of functionality from what I've seen. An example of its use is available at "[Using Ruby Expect Library to Reboot Ruckus Wireless Access Points via ssh](http://pivotallabs.com/using-ruby-expect-library-to-reboot-ruckus-wireless-access-points-via-ssh/)".

Instead, you might want to look at [RubyExpect](https://github.com/abates/ruby_expect) which is better documented and appears to be current.

Comment: I don't want to match a pattern from the output, I want to get it completely without blocking input.

Comment: sorry. Here's a better solution

Comment: OK, when I send a command through the stdin and close it I can read the stdout and stderr. But how will I reopen the stdin to send another command?

Comment: You don't. That's why you need "expect" which watches the interactive responses and then sends the next input.

Comment: OK, apparently I was wrong. At least, I can expect for "gnuplot>" lines, as Thomas suggested. Thank you!