# Capture output of interactive external command run from inside Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, ssh, stdout

I have been searching for a way to run an interactive command (such as `ssh`) and capture its output. This sounds simple but as I understand it, my use case is slightly different from a lot of the google and s/o results.

To be clear, by interactive I mean, the user who runs `my_ruby_script.rb` from the terminal should be able to

1. type into (`stdin`) the running interactive system command (e.g., type `ls` through `ssh` tunnel)
2. read out from (`stdout`/`stderr`) the running interactive system command (again e.g., seeing the output of `ls` in an `ssh` tunnel)

On top of that, I would like to read the output of the system command (`ssh`) so I may, for example, check for errors from inside my Ruby script. The closest that I have gotten has been to simply `tee` the output to another file.

```
system('ssh username@ssh_server |& tee ssh_log.txt')
```

This is not ideal as

1. It requires saving to/reading from a separate file
2. It requires a more complicated system call which may or may not be portable

As I understand it, most of the solutions online (backticks, `Open3.*`, `PTY.spawn()`, etc. ) redirect stdin/stdout away from the terminal interface and into the ruby program. What I'm looking for is to leave `stdin` alone, and tee `stdout` to my Ruby script. Does anybody have any ideas?

I should note that `system('ssh username@ssh_server')` does exactly what I want, I just need to be able to read the output. Additionally, I would prefer not to use net-ssh nor any other non-stdlib libraries.

## Research:

1. This is probably the most comprehensive page describing running commands in Ruby ([When to use each method of launching a subprocess in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212573/when-to-use-each-method-of-launching-a-subprocess-in-ruby) and the linked blog posts).
2. These people have (what seems to me) my exact same issue:

   - [ruby IO.popen or open3 multi write/read operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777295/ruby-io-popen-or-open3-multi-write-read-operations)
   - https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/open3-and-ssh/147475
3. These people are using ssh through Ruby but their scripts aren't "interactive"

   - [Running an interactive program from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682024/running-an-interactive-program-from-ruby)
   - https://content.pivotal.io/blog/using-ruby-expect-library-to-reboot-ruckus-wireless-access-points-via-ssh

I really appreciate any insight you can deliver.

Comment: Couldn't you just `print` the stdout output to the user in your script?

Comment: (after capturing + analyzing)

Comment: Thanks for responding! This would work if I could read the command's `stdout` char-by-char to print it in the terminal (like a manual `tee`) but I think I can't do that since the output will be buffered. This is particularly problematic when there's a line without a `\n` like a terminal prompt e.g., `jmate@ssh_server~$ `.

Comment: I think with popen3 you get an IO object that you can read unbuffered or with a timeout. Also you can then do something like `stdin.copy_stream($stdin)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer! Big thanks to @Kimmo Lehto for suggesting the `IO.copy_stream()` idea which led to my final solution. Basically, we use `PTY.spawn(cmd){|stdin, stdout, pid| ...}` to get unbuffered streams for `stdin` and `stdout`.

Then we copy the script's `stdin` to the command's `stdin` with `IO.copy_stream($stdin.raw!, $stdin)` (don't forget to set `$stdin.cooked!` afterwards).

I couldn't figure out how to use `copy_stream` on the command's `stdout` twice (first to the script's `stdout`, second to a buffer e.g., `io = StringIO.new`) so I had to manually read each character like so: `stdout.readchar(|c| print c; io.write c)`.

Comment: Hi, would you mind posting your final solution? Thanks!

Comment: Wow it's great to see people are still seeing this. Unfortunately, the code for this is owned by Bezos now and I haven't written ruby in years so I'd have a hard time reproducing it.

I will say, the approach I outlined in this post worked perfectly for my purposes.